# Should the "safety" tag go?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There doesn't seem to be much consistency to the [safety](/questions/tagged/safety) tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safety shows some are about thread-safety, some are about input sanitation and general hackproofing, some are about security, and some are pretty random from people who are feeling nervous about what they're doing.

I guess people are making multi-word tags out of individual tags but I'm not sure it's helpful at all. I edited a few that were obvious to me, but perhaps it should be part of a larger plan?

Comment: Any about the [dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Safety_Dance)?